# Creating the hidden slide in affect on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this code here which works perfect like how I want it. How would I make it so instead of sliding in when I click the icons it slides in on hover? I know I have to use the :hover but wasn't sure how exactly to do that.

I created a JSFiddle also the code is found below: http://jsfiddle.net/804jeg82/414/

//script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clickable').on('click' , function() {
      $(this).find('.hid').toggleClass('showme');
    });
});
```

//css

```
.clickable .fa {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #394461; 
}
.clickable .fa, .hid {
  float: left;
}

.hid {
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all ease .35s;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .35s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .35s;
}

.showme {
  width: 150px; 
}
```

//html

```
<div class="clickable"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
  <div class="hid">Phone Number</div>
</div>
<div class="clickable"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
  <div class="hid">Email Here</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/804jeg82/414/

Comment: So when you hover over the icons the text should stay open until you click to close it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the selector `.clickable:hover .hid`.

It will select the descendant `.hid` element when hovering over the parent `.clickable` element:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/bqgubnhr/)

```
.clickable:hover .hid {
  width: 150px;
}
```

The CSS approach is the best option, however, if you need a jQuery alternative:

```
$('.clickable').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.hid').toggleClass('showme');
});
```

---

Based on your comment, if you want the element to stay open until click on it, you could listen to the `mouseenter`/`click` events:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qhkewttz/)

```
$('.clickable').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).find('.hid').addClass('showme');
});
$('.clickable').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find('.hid').removeClass('showme');
});
```

Comment: can I make it so that when it hovers it stays open until you click it to close it?

Comment: @VinceMamba Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clickable').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).find('.hid').addClass('showme');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).find('.hid').removeClass('showme');
        }
    );
});
```